Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
I am trying to add my example qt application to yocto image and then flash it to the stm32 board but I am having problems while doing it . add the dependencies to my local.conf but still having this issue how can I solve it ?
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# ls /usr/lib/qml/QtQuick/Layouts/
libqquicklayoutsplugin.so  plugins.qmltypes  qmldir
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# chmod 755 /usr/lib/qml/QtQuick/Layouts/libqtquicklayoutsplugin.so
chmod: cannot access '/usr/lib/qml/QtQuick/Layouts/libqtquicklayoutsplugin.so': No such file or directory
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# chmod 755 /usr/lib/qml/QtQuick/Layouts/libqquicklayoutsplugin.so
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# run_automotive
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland.

Aborted (core dumped)
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# run_automotive
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland.

Aborted (core dumped)
root@stm32mp15-disco:~# automotive 
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/automotive.qml:5:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Layouts": Cannot protect module QtQuick.Layouts 2 as it was never registered

I added meta-qt5 and meta-st-x-linux-qt layers to my build and I added the
DISTRO = "openstlinux-weston"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " qtbase qtdeclarative qtbase-plugins qtquickcontrols2 qtwayland"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " wayland weston " 
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " automotive "
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " wayland"

dependencies to my local.conf file but it didn't solve the error.
